# Invoking copy constructor/ assignment operator properly for user defined class

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, user-defined-types

I have a class `Point` as shown below:

```
class Point
{
    int x_v = {-1};
    int y_v = {-1};
    int val_v = {0};
    double f_v = {1000000};
    double g_v = {1000000};
    double h_v = {1000000};
    Point* parent_v = nullptr;
public:
    Point(){}
    Point(int x, int y, int val) : x_v{x}, y_v{y}, val_v{val}
    {}
    Point(const Point& p1)
    {
        x_v = p1.x();
        y_v = p1.y();
        val_v = p1.val();
        f_v = p1.f();
        g_v = p1.g();
        h_v = p1.h();
        *(parent_v) = *(p1.parent());
    }
    ~Point(){}

    int val() const
    {
        return val_v;
    }

    int x() const
    {
        return x_v;
    }

    int y() const
    {
        return y_v;
    }

    double f() const
    {
        return f_v;
    }

    double g() const
    {
        return g_v;
    }

    double h() const
    {
        return h_v;
    }

    Point* parent() const
    {
        return parent_v;
    }

    void set_g(double g)
    {
        g_v = g;
        f_v = g_v + h_v;
    }

    void set_h(double h)
    {
        h_v = h;
        f_v = g_v + h_v;
    }

    void set_parent(Point* p)
    {
        parent_v = p;
    }

    Point& operator=(const Point& p1)
    {
        x_v = p1.x();
        y_v = p1.y();
        val_v = p1.val();
        f_v = p1.f();
        g_v = p1.g();
        h_v = p1.h();
        *(parent_v) = *(p1.parent());
        return *this;
    }

    friend bool operator<(const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
    {
        return p1.f() < p2.f();
    }

    friend bool operator==(const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
    {
        std::cout << p1.g() << "\t" << p2.g() << "\n";
        return (p1.x() == p2.x()) && (p1.y() == p2.y()) && (p1.g() == p2.g());
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
    {
        return !(p1 == p2);
    }
};
```

In the later part of the code, there is:

```
std::set<Point> frontier;
frontier.insert(start_v);
start_v.set_g(0);
std::cout << "start g: " << start_v.g() << "\n";
start_v.set_h(this -> manhattan(start_v));
while(!frontier.empty())
{
    Point curr_point = *(std::min_element(frontier.begin(), frontier.end()));
    std::cout << "curr_point g: " << curr_point.g() << "\n";
    /* Other code */
}
```

The reason for creating copy constructor and assignment operator is to make sure that the line:  `Point curr_point = *(std::min_element(frontier.begin(), frontier.end()));`, inside the while loop of the above block, work properly.

The class `Point` is used by another class called `Astar`:

```
class Astar
{
    std::vector<std::vector<Point>> map_v;
    int map_x = {0};
    int map_y = {0};
    Point start_v;
    Point end_v;
    std::vector<Point> path_v;
public:
    Astar(std::vector<std::vector<int>>&, std::pair<int, int>&, std::pair<int, int>&);
    bool is_valid(int, int);
    double manhattan(Point&);
    void search();
    std::vector<Point> path();
};
```

Its constructor:

```
Astar::Astar(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& map, std::pair<int, int>& start, std::pair<int, int>& end)
{
    map_y = map.size();
    if(map_y)
    {
        map_x = map[0].size();
    }
    if(map_x == 0 || map_y == 0)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument{"The map is invalid!\n"};
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < map_y; i++)
    {
        map_v.push_back(std::vector<Point>(map_x));
        for(int j = 0; j < map_x; j++)
        {
            map_v[i][j] = Point(j, i, map[i][j]);
        }
    }
    start_v = Point(start.second, start.first, map[start.first][start.second]);
    end_v = Point(end.second, end.first, map[end.first][end.second]);
    if(!is_valid(start_v.x(), start_v.y()))
    {
        throw std::out_of_range{"Start point is out of range!\n"};
    }
    if(!is_valid(end_v.x(), end_v.y()))
    {
        throw std::out_of_range{"End point is out of range!\n"};
    }
}
```

The problem is that the program terminates when attempted to run. While I ran the debugger, the program terminated in the line:

```
map_v[i][j] = Point(j, i, map[i][j]);
```

This started after the copy constructor and assignment operator of `Point` was added. I am not able to identify the exact problem in this scenario. Kindly help.

**Edit:**

All the previous edits have been removed since the direction of question changed and since the original question was answered.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher for whatever reason, he is using pointers as private members. You definitely don't want `default` constructors for that because they perform a shallow copy.

Comment: Based on the comments, I have changed the copy constructor. But now, it seems that the copy constructor is not being invoked.

Comment: don't edit your answer by making a second question. Repost and narrow down, be specific. If you had 5 answers in your post that would mean that 5 people would need to make an edit accordingly

Comment: Okay. I will repost.

Comment: please narrow down your post, there are many things in your code that are not explanatory. Also your design is not clear. I am stating this because you will get helpful answers by doing so.

Comment: I have created another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52792040/4834108). Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement `map_v[i][j] = Point(j, i, map[i][j]);` is the source of your trouble. Let's parse this a little bit.

```
Point(j, i, map[i][j]) Creates a temporary object of type Point 
                       at this point, due to the Point constructor
                       member variable parent_v is nullptr
map_v[i][j] = ....     This uses the overloaded assignment operator. 
                       Go to its definition and at the end you will see 
                       *(parent_v) = *(p1.parent());
```

So the statement `p1.parent()` will yield `nullptr`. Dereferencing that is UB and will, hopefully, seg fault.

Comment: `*(parent_v)`will also by definition, as `parent_v` is `nullptr` as well.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher dereferencing a `nullptr` is always UB.

Comment: @KostasRim : Please see the edit. It seems that the copy constructor is not being invoked properly. How can I handle the copying of the `parent_v` properly?

Comment: @skr_robo it doesn't call the CCTOR but the overloaded assignment operator. Anyway, the problem is replicated in both of your constructors (copy and assignment). I have told you, you are dereferencing a `nullptr`. I have no clue what you want to achieve but you can just copy the pointer if that's something that you want (which can create all sorts of problems if you are not careful)

Comment: @KostasRim I'm not saying the opposite?? And indeed, the default pointer will be better than what we have here, but will lead to segfaults later as the pointers will be dangling and not updated when the vectors are resized.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher a dangling pointer is a pointer that points to an invalidated memory location(maybe because it was freed).  In the above case a `nullptr` is dereferenced which causes the seg fault :)

Comment: @KostasRim I have changed the part where I was dereferencing `nullptr`. I have made two edits in the question. Please take a look.

Comment: I'm talking about the error after he fixes the current issue, he will still have the problem of dangling pointers.